# newton.method issues

Tags: r

Is this method broken in R? I am using it to find roots of the following function:
f(x) = 2.5*exp(-0.5*(2*0.045 - x)) + 2.5*exp(-0.045) + 2.5*exp(-1.5*x) - 100

It is giving an answer of -38.4762403 which is not even close (f(x) = 2.903809e+25 for x=-38.4762403). The answer should be around 0.01-0.1. This function should converge..

Even for a simple function like  f(x) = exp(-x) * x, it gives answer as 8.89210984 for which f(x) = 0.001222392 and I set tolerance to 10^-12..

Also, is there a non graphical version of newton method? I looked at nleqslv but have no idea how to use it..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has a number of root finders, such as `uniroot` and `polyroot`. For more complicated problems you can use optimisation functions such as `optim`, `optimize` or `nlminb`. Here is an example of solving this problem with `uniroot`.

```
## define the function
f <- function(x){                                                                                                                                            
  2.5*exp(-0.5*(2*0.045 - x)) + 2.5*exp(-0.045) + 2.5*exp(-1.5*x) - 100                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                            

## plot the function 
y <- seq(-20,20,0.1) 
plot(y,f(y),ylim = c(-100,100),xlim=c(-20,20))

## find the roots
uniroot(f,c(-5,0))
uniroot(f,c(0,10))
```

Comment: That is so cool. This would sure come handy back in high school!

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it uses something similar to bisection method. Your call should be uniroot(f,c(-5,5)) for this to work. I am still searching for a working version of newton's method :(